# Removing uneven spaces from input file in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a text file which contains balance sheet information for the company. The problem is that the spacing is uneven and I get data like this

```
28/07/15                 2.85                                104,689.13
30/07/15                                 31,862.00           136,551.13
```

The reason is that 2.85 on first line is a debit and second is a credit.

How can I get the data in ruby so that I get 4 elements from the line with credit being empty on first and debit on second.

I can split the data based on multiple spaces and then compare the balance between successive lines to get credit vs debit information but I want to know if there is a better way(maybe regex) to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: This is why no one in their right minds uses variable-space delimited values. Go back to your data source and export as CSV, which is reliably parseable.

Comment: @CodeGnome I tried telling them with almost the same statement as yours. :) The problem is that the data I get is converted to text from a pdf table.

Comment: I agree with @CodeGnome's first sentence, but that's not relevant to the question. Some messy data has been dumped in your lap and you have to deal with it. The messiness is what makes the problem interesting. In fact, the messier the better!

Comment: @CarySwoveland I agree, it is an interesting problem. I tried to use regex but it was hard to generalise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way that will work even if the lines are really messed up. It relies on the fact that debits (credits) reduce (increase) the balance by the amount of the debit (credit). Let's first write some data to file:

```
data =<<_
28/07/15                 2.85  104,689.13
30/07/15        31,862.00                                    136,551.13
                                 28/07/15 1.13 136,550.00
30/07/15                                 10,000.01           146,550.01
_

FName = 'temp'
IO.write(FName, data)
  #=> 288
```

The method for extracting the fields follows. It requires the file name and starting balance. Alternatively, the second argument could be a boolean indicating whether the first line contains a debit or a credit.

```
require 'bigdecimal'

def extract_transactions(fname, starting_balance)
  transactions = []
  IO.readlines(FName).reduce(BigDecimal.new(starting_balance)) do |start_bal,s|
    date, debit_or_credit, bal = s.strip.delete(',').split(/\s+/)
    h = { date: date, debit: '', credit: '', balance: bal }
    if BigDecimal.new(bal) == start_bal - BigDecimal.new(debit_or_credit)
      h[:debit] = debit_or_credit
    else
      h[:credit] = debit_or_credit
    end
    transactions << h
    BigDecimal.new(bal)
  end
  transactions          
end
```

Let's try it:

```
extract_debits_and_credits(FName, "104691.98")
  #=> [{:date=>"28/07/15", :debit=>"2.85", :credit=>"", :balance=>"104689.13"},
  #    {:date=>"30/07/15", :debit=>"", :credit=>"31862.00", :balance=>"136551.13"},
  #    {:date=>"28/07/15", :debit=>"1.13", :credit=>"", :balance=>"136550.00"},
  #    {:date=>"30/07/15", :debit=>"", :credit=>"10000.01", :balance=>"146550.01"}]
```

I used [BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) to avoid problems with round-off errors.

[Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`) updates the balance (`start_bal`, initially `starting_balance`) after each transaction (row).

**Edit:** here's a non-`BigDecimal` variant (that's better):

```
def extract_transactions(fname, debit_first)
  curr_bal = (debit_first ? Float::INFINITY : -Float::INFINITY)
  IO.readlines(FName).each_with_object([]) do |s, transact|
    date, debit, bal = s.strip.split(/\s+/)
    credit = ''
    bal_float = bal.delete(',').to_f
    (debit, credit = credit, debit) if bal_float > curr_bal
    transact << { date: date, debit: debit, credit: credit, balance: bal }
    curr_bal = bal_float
  end
end

extract_transactions(FName, true)
  #=> [{:date=>"28/07/15", :debit=>"2.85", :credit=>"", :balance=>"104689.13"},
  #    {:date=>"30/07/15", :debit=>"", :credit=>"31862.00", :balance=>"136551.13"},
  #    {:date=>"28/07/15", :debit=>"1.13", :credit=>"", :balance=>"136550.00"},
  #    {:date=>"30/07/15", :debit=>"", :credit=>"10000.01", :balance=>"146550.01"}]
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be the best way to go around it.

Comment: Nice approach! Though it requires to a `starting_balance` for the first row, which I don't think is provided, if I haven't misread the OP.

Comment: Edited to include a variable that I think is better.

Answer (score 1):

The only constant you have is the string length (71, but 72 is divided by 4 and therefore is a correct value). We might try to use it:

```
▶ data = %q|28/07/15                 2.85                                104,689.13
▷ 30/07/15                                 31,862.00           136,551.13|
▶ data.split($/).map do |line|
▷   #                         ⇓⇓ ≡ string length + 1 / amount of items
▷   line.split(//).each_slice(18).map(&:join).map(&:strip)
▷ end
#⇒ [
#  [0] [
#    [0] "28/07/15",
#    [1] "2.85",
#    [2] "",
#    [3] "104,689.13"
#  ],
#  [1] [
#    [0] "30/07/15",
#    [1] "",
#    [2] "31,862.00",
#    [3] "136,551.13"
#  ]
# ]
```

Comment: I like your solution but it didnt work when there was an additional column with more data. I gave the last 4 columns, but there is a description column as well which has a variable length

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the data in ruby so that I get 4 elements from the line 
>   with credit being empty on first and debit on second.
>   I want to know if there is a better way(maybe regex)
>
> > I gave the last 4 columns

I will assume the following column widths:

```
+--------------+--------+----------------------------+------------------+-----------------+
|Previous col  | DATE   | DEBIT                      | CREDIT           | BALANCE         |
| (any width)  | width=8|  (width=28)                |  (width=18)      |  (width=17)     |
+--------------+--------+----------------------------+------------------+-----------------+
|      ...     |28/07/15|                 2.85       |                  |       104,689.13|
|      ...     |30/07/15|                            |     31,862.00    |       136,551.13|
+--------------+--------+----------------------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

If you think about it, we can match the whole width of the last column with `/.{17}$/`. The *trick* here is to use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to capture the value of the field, from the position 17 chars to the left of the end of the line, and moving forward:

```regex
/(?=[ ]{0,16}([\d,.]+)).{17}$/
```

*Credit* is the previous column, and its width is 18 characters `/.{18}/`, but since it's an optional field, we need to enclose the lookahead in an optional group. If we prefix this pattern to the last regex, we now have:

```regex
/(?:(?=[ ]{0,17}([\d,.]+)))?.{18}(?=[ ]{0,16}([\d,.]+)).{17}$/
```

And we use the same logic to complete all 4 fields into this one-liner regex (break-down in the code below):

```regex
/(?=[ ]{0,7}(?<date>[\d\/]+)).{8}(?:(?=[ ]{0,27}(?<debit>[\d,.]+)))?.{28}(?:(?=[ ]{0,17}(?<credit>[\d,.]+)))?.{18}(?=[ ]{0,16}(?<balance>[\d,.]+)).{17}[ ]*$/
```

- Notice I'm using [named groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) for both readability and practicality in the code.

**[regex101 DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wG0lP9/1)**

---

#### Code:

```ruby
data = %q|28/07/15                 2.85                                104,689.13
30/07/15                                 31,862.00           136,551.13|

regex = /
    (?=[ ]{0,7}(?<date>[\d\/]+))          # Field 1: date
    .{8}                                  #  column 1 (width=8)
                                          #
    (?:(?=[ ]{0,27}(?<debit>[\d,.]+)))?   # Field 2: debit (optional)
    .{28}                                 #  column 2 (width=28)
                                          #
    (?:(?=[ ]{0,17}(?<credit>[\d,.]+)))?  # Field 3: credit (optional)
    .{18}                                 #  column 3 (width=18)
                                          #
    (?=[ ]{0,16}(?<balance>[\d,.]+))      # Field 4: balance
    .{17}                                 #  column 4 (width=17)
                                          #
    [ ]*$                                 # optional spaces -> EoL
/x


# hash from all named captures from all matches
result = data.scan(regex).collect do |match| Hash[regex.names.zip(match)] end

p result
#=> [{"date"=>"28/07/15", "debit"=>"2.85", "credit"=>nil, "balance"=>"104,689.13"}, 
#    {"date"=>"30/07/15", "debit"=>nil, "credit"=>"31,862.00", "balance"=>"136,551.13"}]
```

- **[ideone DEMO](http://ideone.com/ICCJt0)**

Comment: A miniucule point: you can replace `%r{` and `}x` with `/` and `/x`, respectively.

Comment: I'm a big fan of extended mode (`/x`) and use it in all my answers when the regex is not dead simple. It greatly facilitates both documentation and comprehension.

Comment: `%r{..}x` and `/../x` are equivalents. I changed it because the latter is more generally recognized as a regex.

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try this one out. I was hoping to find a regex solution that I could apply in any case. With named groups and column lengths, I can apply this to any output provided I have the header.

Comment: Another option is to capture leading and trailing spaces in `credit/debit` and compare. If it has more spaces to the right, it's `debit`, if it has more spaces to the left, it's `credit` ([ideone DEMO](http://ideone.com/dvP8iL)). I thought the posted solution would work better for the general case though.